# Discord.py "This interaction failed" when I'm using ui.select

Tags: discord.py

I have this:

```
class NewsView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, author, guild_id, channel_id):
        super().__init__()
        self.author = author
        self.guild_id = guild_id
        self.channel_id = channel_id
        self.select_news = discord.ui.Select(placeholder='Choose news', options=[])
        self.add_item(self.select_news)

    async def get_news_list(self):
        guild = client.get_guild(self.guild_id)
        if not guild:
            return ["Server not found."]
        channel = guild.get_channel(self.channel_id)
        if not channel:
            return ["News channel not found."]
        news_list = []
        async for message in channel.history(limit=100):
            if "/" in message.content:
                news_list.append(message.content)
        return news_list

    async def interaction_check(self, interaction: discord.Interaction) -> bool:
        return interaction.user == self.author

    async def select_news_interaction(self, select: discord.ui.Select, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        news = await self.get_news(select.values[0])
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"News for {select.values[0]}", color=0xAE6C72)
        embed.set_image(url=news)
        await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed)

    async def get_news(self, date):
        guild = client.get_guild(self.guild_id)
        if not guild:
            return "Server not found."
        channel = guild.get_channel(self.channel_id)
        if not channel:
            return "News channel not found."
        async for message in channel.history(limit=100):
            if date in message.content:
                if message.attachments:
                    return message.attachments[0].url
        return "News not found"


@client.command(name='news', aliases=['newspaper'], pass_context=True)
async def news(ctx, date: str = None):
    guild_id = xxx
    channel_id = xxx
    if date:
        guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
        if not guild:
            return await ctx.send("Server not found.")
        channel = guild.get_channel(channel_id)
        if not channel:
            return await ctx.send("News channel not found.")
        messages = []
        async for message in channel.history(limit=100):
            if date in message.content:
                messages.append(message)
        if messages:
            message = messages[0]
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"News for {date}", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(174,108,114))
            if message.attachments:
                for attachment in message.attachments:
                    embed.set_image(url=attachment.url)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"News for {date} not found.")
    else:
        guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
        if not guild:
            return await ctx.send("Server not found.")
        channel = guild.get_channel(channel_id)
        if not channel:
            return await ctx.send("News channel not found.")
        messages = []
        async for message in channel.history(limit=1):
            messages.append(message)
        if messages:
            last_message = messages[0]
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Last news — {last_message.content}", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(174,108,114))
            embed.description = f"\nTo see newspapers for other months, select them from the list"
            if last_message.attachments:
                for attachment in last_message.attachments:
                    embed.set_image(url=attachment.url)
            view = NewsView(ctx.author, guild_id, channel_id)
            news_list = await view.get_news_list()
            for news in news_list:
                view.select_news.options.append(discord.SelectOption(label=news, value=news))
            await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)
        else:
            await ctx.send("Newspapers not found")
```

In the channel, I have messages in the format: [mm/yy] and each one has a picture attached to it.When I use the command, the bot does give the latest message from the channel, but when I try to select a different newspaper from the list, I get "This interaction failed", with no error in the console. What's wrong there?

I tried sending a new embed instead of editing an existing embed, but it didn't help and still gets this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select menu that you have added to the view does not have a callback. You have to assign its callback.

```
class NewsView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, author, guild_id, channel_id):
        super().__init__()
        self.select_news = discord.ui.Select(placeholder='Choose news', options=[])
        self.select_news.callback = self.select_news_interaction
        self.add_item(self.select_news)
```

Another thing, If you were to add the select menu and assign the callback like this, the callback function only takes in the `interaction` parameter.

```
class NewsView(discord.ui.View):
    ...
    async def select_news_interaction(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        values = interaction.data["values"][0]
```

and without `select` you can get the select values from the `Interaction.data`.

Documentation: [discord.ui.View](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.View), [select.callback](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.Select.callback), [interaction.data](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction.data)